# PHP ImageMagick split large image to tiles

Tags: php, perl, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to split a large image to smaller tiles. I tried it using PHP ImageMagick `cropImage()` and I could do it successfully with the following code.

```
for($w = 0; $w < ($large_image_width/$tile_width); $w++){
    for($h = 0; $h < ($large_image_height/$tile_height); $h++){
        $X = $w*$tile_width;
        $Y = $h*$tile_height;

        $image = new Imagick($input_file);
        $image->cropImage($tile_width,$tile_height, $X,$Y);
        $image->writeImage("X" . ($w+1) . "Y" . ($h+1) . ".jpg");
    }
}
```

But it loops through each tile size and load the image again and again.

When I did more research, I found this [link](http://michael.otacoo.com/linux-2/split-an-image-file-into-tiles/), which is a one liner using the command line.

```
convert -crop $WIDTHx$HEIGHT@ huge_file.png  tile_%d.png
```

I am wondering if the PHP ImageMagick extension got any function to do the same. Also I am comfortable to switch to Perl or someother library like GD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the `$input_file` I/O by loading the image once, then cloning the object.

```php
$source_image = new Imagick($input_file);
for($w = 0; $w < ($large_image_width/$tile_width); $w++){
    for($h = 0; $h < ($large_image_height/$tile_height); $h++){
        $X = $w*$tile_width;
        $Y = $h*$tile_height;

        $image = clone $source_image;
        $image->cropImage($tile_width,$tile_height, $X,$Y);
        $image->writeImage("X" . ($w+1) . "Y" . ($h+1) . ".jpg");
    }
}
```

You can also optimize & reduce the for loop, or just call the one liner directly.

```php
system("convert -crop $WIDTHx$HEIGHT@ $input_file  tile_%d.png");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clone way. And yeah, I am aware of the system command. I meant, Is there any method in PHP ImageMagick extension itself?

Comment: In the PECL extension itself, there is not. You can mimic the behavior by combining Imagick::cropImage & Imagick::setImagePage, but what your already doing is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

[libvips](https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/) has a [php binding](https://github.com/jcupitt/php-vips) now and it can do this task very quickly using only a little memory.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jcupitt\Vips;

$im = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1]);
$im->dzsave($argv[2], ["overlap" => 0, "tile-size" => 256, "depth" => "one"]);
```

On this laptop with a 10k x 10k jpeg image, I see:

```
$ time ./try260.php ~/pics/wtc.jpg x
real    0m2.262s
user    0m3.596s
sys 0m1.256s
```

And it's created 1369 jpeg files in `x_files`:

```
$ ls x_files/0/ | wc
   1369    1369   14319
```

There's a blogpost here about the `dzsave` operator (the libvips thing that's being used here):

http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html